# Temps de la principale après une subordonnée introduite par "dans le cas où"

Tags: conditionnel, concordance-des-temps

Je voudrais savoir si l'emploi des temps dans la phrase suivante est correct:

> Dans le cas où un enfant poserait quand même la question, on lui répond toujours que ce n'est pas possible.

La situation est la suivante. Les enfants posent rarement la question, mais quand cela arrive, on leur répond à chaque fois que ce n'est pas possible.

Je m'interroge, car une réponse que j'ai trouvée [ici](http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/topic35301-conditionnel-ou-indicatif-apres-les-conjonctions-ou-locutions-conjonctives.html) semble indiquer que la concordance des temps est obligatoire.

Je ne veux pas utiliser le conditionnel dans la principale (« répondrait »), car c'est quelque chose qui arrive effectivement de temps en temps. Mais dans la subordonnée, je préfère le conditionnel (plutôt que « pose ») pour souligner que c'est rare, et que c'est une hypothèse quand on envisage les choses du point de vue d'un seul enfant.

Comment: Un élément de la structure qui me perturbe est "répond toujours".  
Le début est au conditionnel (dans le futur), et la suite est une vérité générale, il y a bien quelque chose qui cloche... La réponse étant dans le futur, il faut que "répondre" soit au futur pour être cohérent. Sinon, il faut que tout soit au présent.

Comment: @Random On ne peut pas considérer qu'il s'agit d'un présent de vérité générale (renforcé par la présence de « toujours ») ?

Comment: @Chop Comment ça ? je ne suis pas sûr de comprendre la question :)

Comment: @Random « On répond toujours » -> Le présent ne me choque pas. Pour moi, c'est une vérité générale.

Answer (score 1):

Pour moi, la concordance des temps est bien obligatoire, sémantiquement parlant. Ta phrase devient donc :

> Dans le cas où un enfant poserait quand même la question, on lui
>   répondrait que ce n'est pas possible.

Ici, le "toujours" disparait car il est sous-entendu par la phrase elle même : Pas de doute, si un enfant pose la question, on lui répond que ce n'est pas possible.

Cependant, à l'oral, ta phrase est parfaitement compréhensible quand même. Si c'est simplement pour expliquer une façon de faire à quelqu'un, tu peux continuer d'utiliser:

> Dans le cas où un enfant poserait quand même la question, on lui
>   répond toujours que ce n'est pas possible.

mais c'est un peu plus formel et un peu moins correct.

Comment: Pourquoi pas un futur dans la deuxième, ou un présent dans la première ?

Answer (score 0):

je pense que si c'est une généralité intemporelle, on peut dire "on répond toujours", tandis que si c'est spécifique au sujet, il faut accorder "on lui répondrais - comme toujours - que".

"On lui répond toujours" semble donc une forme chimérique, impropre. 
De même que "On répondrait toujours", bien que possiblement moins grave.